# symfony doctrine pivot table with multiple keys

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, annotations

Imagine the following usecase describing it just schemantically, but i belive it is enough:

1-have some kind of entities, lets call the company and person:

```
company (id=uuid, name=string, files=hasMany(File), ... )
person (id=uuid, name=string, files=hasMany(File), ... )
```

2-have a file entity like :

```
file (id=uuid, fileName=string, filePath=string, ...)
```

at some point i would like to store File for Company or Person or any other entity, in a pivot table (one single pivot table, not a different one for each EntityType-File relation).

this would mean having a pivot table like

```
fileId | entityId | entityType
1         2          CLIENT
2         2          PERSON
.....
```

and so on. note the difference in the entityType: entityId is the same (2) but the type is different, bsicly this translates to "fileId(2) belongs to the id 2 of the Person entity).

how could i map this in the entity using doctrine and annotations? the basic problem is to introduce the entityType column and set it for each entity to a constant (it could be a string like CLIENT or an int (like 1 = client, 2 = person ...)

this way the only one File entity could be reused on any number of entities of any kind, where file(s) upload is needed.

can someone point me in a right direction?

Comment: I don't think this is doable with standard doctrine annotations. Though you could experiment with [mapped superclasses and single table inheritance](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance).

Comment: well, after a few hours of experimenting it seems like your answer is theoreticly good, anyway it implies another set of questions, so i solved it the "old school way". but in theory probably your answer is good. thank you.